# save Data ( List<model>) from Grid after Editting GXT-GWT

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

I have a grid(including one editable column). Grid source like this:

```
listStore = new ListStore<DeleteAllTestModel>();
listStore.add(listDatas);
gridView = new PMTGridDeleteAllTest<DeleteAllTestModel>()
    .getPMTGridDeleteAllTest(listStore);
```

`listDatas` is an `ArrayList` storing `<model>`

After editing is done, i use saveButton to save store, but i check `listDatas` doesn't change

```
cp.addButton(new Button("Save", new SelectionListener<ButtonEvent>() {    
    @Override  
    public void componentSelected(ButtonEvent ce) {  
        listStore.commitChanges();  
    }  
}));
```

How can i save data to `listDatas` after editing ? help me

Comment: Is `listStore` and `store` are same? Also check, whether the `BuutonEvent` is getting fired or not, upon click. I would suggest use `GXT TextButton` and add a 'SelectionHandler' to it, that listens to 'SelectEvent'

Comment: Yes, listStore and store are same ^^.. it is not working @@

Comment: You should also check whether the event is getting fired or not upon clicking. have a look at the examples 
http://qa.sencha.com:8080/examples-3.0.6/#ExamplePlace:inlineeditablegrid for GXT 3.0.X
and http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:inlineeditablegrid for GXT 3.1.x

Comment: `listDatas` seem to be the model instance (of DeleteAllTestModel). It is not binded with ListStore, so it will not reflect the changes of ListStore. You have to get the changed data from listStore by using `listStore.get(int index)`. You can easily keep track of index